# Is the collection of set algebras of a finite set itself a Boolean algebra?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, boolean-algebra

For example, say $\Omega$ is a finite set and $(\Omega,S,\mu)$ is a probability triple defining the uniform distribution over atoms of $\Omega$.

The meet algebra of two sub-algebras of $S$ is well defined by intersection and a join algebra can be generated from the union.
Do these join and meet operations on the collection of sub-algebras of S themselves form a Boolean algebra?

I am going down the list of axioms and can readily establish several of them. I am not sure if both Distributivity laws hold. I am really looking for a reference or counterexample for this seemingly basic question.

Comment: Are you asking if the Boolean subalgebras of a finite Boolean algebra form a Boolean algebra when ordered by inclusion?

Comment: I don’t think so. I believe the answer to the question you set up in your comment is “no” since for $a, b$ any two concrete boolean subalgebras, $a\cup b$ is not necessarily a boolean subalgebra. (but as i note you can still find a concrete subalgebra $a\vee b$

Comment: Well, the answer to that question is indeed negative, but to show this it is not sufficient to observe that the union of two Boolean subalgebra need not be a Boolean subalgebra.

Comment: Let me rephrase: are you asking if the Boolean subalgebras of a finite Boolean algebra (i.e. the powerset of a finite set) together with the operations of taking the intersection of two Boolean subalgebras and the operation $a \vee b$ that you mention form a Boolean algebra?

Comment: oh i see. if i understand what you’re getting at, the inclusion relation defines a greatest lower bound and least upper bound, which are the join and meet in my original post. but these join and meet do not satisfy all the boolean algebra laws

Comment: Correct, they do not in general form a distributive lattice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each finite Boolean algebra is isomorphic to the powerset $\mathcal{P}(X)$ of a finite set $X$. The Boolean subalgebras of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ ordered by inclusion form a lattice which is isomorphic to the order dual of the lattice of equivalence relations on $X$.

(Proof sketch: given an equivalence relation $\theta$ on $X$, the subsets of $X$ closed under $\theta$ form a Boolean subalgebra. Conversely, given a Boolean subalgebra $\mathbf{B}$ of $\mathcal{P}(X)$, consider the equivalence relation $\theta$ such that $\langle a, b \rangle \in \theta$ if and only if for each $U \in \mathbf{B}$ we have $a \in U \iff b \in U$.)

This lattice is not distributive for $| X | \geq 3$.